# What should be the speed of my bullet be to punch a nice round hole through a paper sheet?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, material-science, collision, projectile

If my bullet travels faster will the amount of damage done to the paper be lesser?

Due to inertia of the paper can the bullet make bullet shaped holes instead of making a big hole as the speed increases.

Is this possible?

Comment: You will find this book very relevant : The Bullet's flight by F.W. Mann.  So are you saying that if the bullet goes fast enough it will go through the paper but not make hole?

Comment: No, It'll make a hole but the hole will be the perfect circular shape of the longitudinal diameter of the bullet instead of making an ugly tear in the piece of paper.

Comment: No, it won't be a "perfect circular shape" as the paper is not perfectly homogenous...

Comment: If it was, will it make a circular hole, and how does homegeneity affect the outcome?

Comment: What is paper made of? then think about the structure.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on a number of factors, such as the type of paper, the shape of the bullet, whether the paper has a backing of some sort like an Army figure target and so on. I have fired all sorts of bullets with all sorts of velocities at paper targets which usually had a backing of plywood, but was never able to make a completely smooth, round hole. Mostly I fired sharp-pointed 7.62 mm bullets at paper targets backed with plywood. These bullets had a muzzle velocity of 2 800 feet per second, but even when going through a paper patch which happened to have nothing behind it, the hole was not smooth-edged and circular. The exit side was more ragged than the entry hole. Very likely there is some exotic mix of bullet, paper, muzzle velocity etc which would give the type of hole you want, but it would not be the sort of stuff usually found on a shooting range.

Comment: I think the velocity of the bullet has to be very high as compared to the speed of the bullet you are talking about.

Comment: The highest velocity bullet I know of is about 3,150 ft per sec (Armalite 15),& I don't think you would find any firearm with a much higher muzzle velocity than that. These ultra-high velocity guns used in laboratories to explore the effect of asteroid impacts do reach much higher velocities,but I don't think you could persuade the scientists responsible to use them for cutting very neat,smooth edged,round holes in pieces of paper.